# Grouping ElasticSearch documents on xml tag value (in a string field)

Tags: json, xml, elasticsearch, aggregate

I have this kind of documents on my ElasticSearch index :

```
{
    "took" : 31,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 68,
        "successful" : 68,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : 9103,
        "max_score" : 8.823501,
        "hits" : [{
                "_index" : "ESB",
                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                "_score" : 8.823501,
                "_source" : {
                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>123</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:17</timeStamp><step>1</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                }
            }, {
                "_index" : "ESB",
                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                "_score" : 8.823501,
                "_source" : {
                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>123</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:17</timeStamp><step>2</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                }
            }, {
                "_index" : "ESB",
                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                "_score" : 8.823501,
                "_source" : {
                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>123</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:18</timeStamp><step>3</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                }
            }, {
                "_index" : "ESB",
                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                "_score" : 8.823501,
                "_source" : {
                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>123</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:26</timeStamp><step>1</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                }
            }, {
                "_index" : "ESB",
                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                "_score" : 8.823501,
                "_source" : {
                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>456</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:27</timeStamp><step>2</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                }
            }, {
                "_index" : "ESB",
                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                "_score" : 8.823501,
                "_source" : {
                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>456</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:27</timeStamp><step>3</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                }
            }, {
                "_index" : "ESB",
                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                "_score" : 8.823501,
                "_source" : {
                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>456</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:17</timeStamp><step>2</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is the XML format of the message field:

```
<root>
    <flux>MyFlux</flux>
    <requestId>123</requestId>
    <timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:17</timeStamp>
    <step>2</step>
    <status>ok</status>
    <body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body>
</root>
```

**I‘d like to build a query that could group my documents on the RequestId value (which is in the XML content of the message field).**
I expect this kind of answer :

```
{
    "took" : 31,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 68,
        "successful" : 68,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : 9103,
        "max_score" : 8.823501,
        "hits" : [...],
        "aggregations" : {
            "myaggs" : {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                "buckets" : [{
                        "key" : "123",
                        "documents" : [{
                                "_index" : "ESB",
                                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                                "_score" : 8.823501,
                                "_source" : {
                                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>123</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:17</timeStamp><step>1</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "_index" : "ESB",
                                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                                "_score" : 8.823501,
                                "_source" : {
                                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>123</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:17</timeStamp><step>2</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "_index" : "ESB",
                                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                                "_score" : 8.823501,
                                "_source" : {
                                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>123</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:18</timeStamp><step>3</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "key" : "456",
                        "documents" : [{
                                "_index" : "ESB",
                                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                                "_score" : 8.823501,
                                "_source" : {
                                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>123</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:26</timeStamp><step>1</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "_index" : "ESB",
                                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                                "_score" : 8.823501,
                                "_source" : {
                                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>456</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:27</timeStamp><step>2</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "_index" : "ESB",
                                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                                "_score" : 8.823501,
                                "_source" : {
                                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>456</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:27</timeStamp><step>3</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "_index" : "ESB",
                                "_type" : "MDOrderFO",
                                "_id" : "AVaxDzEGBclOg4W8YiW1",
                                "_score" : 8.823501,
                                "_source" : {
                                    "message" : "<root><flux>MyFlux</flux><requestId>456</requestId><timeStamp>2016-26-08T09:37:17</timeStamp><step>2</step><status>ok</status><body><xml><myobject><field1>value1</field1></myobject></xml></body></root>",
                                    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
                                    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I’m very new with ElasticSearch and I spent a week on this… and at this time, I don’t even know if this is possible.

I really hope you’ll be able to help me.
Thank you in advance.

And of course, as a French speaker, sorry for my English

**EDIT**
 - Unfortunatly I can't edit the mapping. I don't have access to the part of the process which is saving logs into E.S.
 - Actually, the formats i gave are quiet simplified against reality. There plenty of other technical information logged at the mapping level and in the XML content.
The context : The BUS application that pushes logs into E.S. has 3 steps (1: receiving, 2: routing, 3: sending). It logs information about the state of a request (ok, fail) and the object that is transiting in this request.
The purpose of the application I'm working on is to display business informations about all the requests that have transited is the BUS application for a date range. 
So in my query, I want to : 
 1. Aggregate my logs by RequestId (each group should contains 1 log at receiving step, 0 or 1 log at routing step and 0 or 1 log at sending step)
 2. Filter the resulting groups on the date of the log at the receiving step
 3. Take the first 10 groups ordered by date descending

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is by modifying your database schema. Since your xml schema is fixed you can store each xml node in a separate filed in Elastic instead of storing entire xml in a single field. For example `flux`,`requestId`,`timeStamp` etc will be mapped to separate filed (may be of same name) in Elastic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but like I say in my edit :  I can't change the mapping :/

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you want to achieve here, so I'll try to point out some things you could consider and/or try:

The way you store data in your ES index is not very query friendly, no matter what you are trying to achieve.
I would suggest breaking your `XML` documents and storing each attribute in separate fields, like this:

```
"_source" : {
    "flux": "My Flux",
    "requestId": 123,
    "xml_timeStamp": "2016-26-08T09:37:17",
    "step": 1,
    "status": "ok",
    "field1": "value1",
    "timestamp" : "2016-08-22T07:02:57.085Z",
    "logger_name" : "MDOrderFOToFO"
}
```

This way of storing your data would mean you'd only need to use a [value count aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) for your aggregation.

In order to achieve this, you'd probably need a method that would break your `XML` documents and map it to this new ElasticSearch mapping.

In this case, your aggregation query would look something similar to:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "myaggs" : {
            "avg_price" : { "value_count" : { "field" : "requestId" } }
        }
    }
}
```

If it's impossible for you to update your index mapping, I would suggest looking into the [regex filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html) and include that in an aggregation query.

Either way, those `aggregations` won't return you the documents inside each bucket. There is no good use case to want to return all documents in Elasticsearch or any other type of database. It would be a very memory intensive operation and, also, slow.

If you'd like your documents to be returned ordered by the `requestId`, then consider changing the index mapping to the one I suggested above. Then use [sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) to return your data.

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but like I say in my edit : I can't change the mapping :/

Comment: So, if I manage to aggregate on the RequestId using RegExp in the first step, should I, query on each RequestId returned at first ?

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve. If you need a list of all documents ordered by `requestId`, then just use the `sort` I mentioned. If you need all documents with a specific `requestId`, then use the `regex` query to extract those documents.

Comment: By the looks of your example, it looks like you want all documents, ordered by `requestId`, so I am not sure why the aggregation part. If my understanding is wrong, could you please add another edit specifying what the end result should be? Thanks

Comment: I've edited my post to explain what is my need (and with the context for you to understand well). I hope you'll understand better. 
don't hesitate to tell me if i'm on the wrong way to do what I want to do.